# can i specify a compositview's itemview template at runtime?

Tags: marionette

I'm trying to specify a template to be rendered at run time for the compositView itemview.

if so can some one post an example
the itemViewOptions wont work

10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function that you need is getTemplate,here you  define the behavior you need to decide which template to use at runtime, define this in your ItemView.

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   getTemplate: function(){
     if (this.model.get("foo")){
         return "#some-template";
     } else {
        return "#a-different-template";
     }
  }
});
```

Here is the link to the documentation.
    https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtemplatehelpers

Edit

I created a JS fiddle, this is just an example of how to pass options to the itemView from the composite View.
http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/bCkUe/

```
var SampleCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template : "#compositeViewTemplate",
    templatetoUseinItemView : '#sample-template2',
    itemView : SampleView,
    buildItemView: function(item, ItemViewType, itemViewOptions){
         var options = _.extend({model: item}, itemViewOptions);
         options.templatetoUseinItemView = this.templatetoUseinItemView;
         var view = new ItemViewType(options);
         return view;
    },   
});
```

If you need to do an extra set up of ge the template based in your options value you still can use the getTemplate function of the ItemView.
As I dont know your code at all this is be best example that I can provide.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help me, i actually need to pass dynamic parameters to the itemViewOptions object, but apparently i canot do that itemViewOptions:{ param: function(){return "string"})}, wont work

Comment: did you tried the buildItemView function? this work for the composite and for the collectionView of marionette. you can take a look here https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-builditemview

Comment: in that function you can pass the options to the itemView

Comment: can i specify template on runtime with buildItemView? can you post an example? how can i specify a template for the itemview from the compositeView, thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Is the example on the JsFiddle helpful?

Comment: Hi Rayweb, thanks for the post, i am also facing some issue to generalize my need. I am trying to create a table using for that i have to pass header information for the table and collection which holds the model and itemView which actually holds the row values. How do i go about to build the above one.

Comment: @Anto Hi i think the compositeView is what you are looking for, in the compositeView you can pass a model which will hold the values for your header and a collection that will be rendered using an itemView just like the collectionView. If you neeed more help please create a question an paste the link here so I get a notification.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay, I am from India, It was late and left the office. that is why i was not able to reply back. I have created a question and You have already answered for that too. Great Help, Thanks a lot. I have also commented there.

Answer (score 1):

Another way around I did was by passing template selector as one of the items in itemViewOptions.

```
MyCompositeViewInstance = new MyCompositeView(
                         {collection: col,
                          itemViewOptions: { template:"#myTemplate"});
```

In the itemView's initialize(), the default value of template can be changed like so:

```
if(options.template) {
this.template = options.template;
}
```

The view now renders using the new template by overriding the initial value specified as default in ItemView.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's worth noting that for `CompositeView` the hash key to set is `childViewOptions`.